# Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

I have a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, or a `java.util.Calendar` object. How do I convert that to the right type in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework?

I have heard that we should now be doing the bulk of our business logic with java.time types. When working with old code not yet updated for java.time I need to be able to convert back and forth. What types map to `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: Thanks for asking (and for answering)! Why not to use JodaTime BTW?

Comment: @aviad JodaTime was necessary before Java 8's new Time API (which was influenced a lot by JodaTime I believe, maybe even by the same people). It's not that useful anymore.

Comment: @aviad The java.time framework is the official replacement for Joda-Time. Both projects are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne ([“jodastephen”](http://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen)).

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Yes, you definitely should be using the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework whenever possible.

## Avoid old date-time classes

The old date-time classes including [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and such have proven to be [poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/642706). Avoid them where you can. But when you must interoperate with these old types, you can convert between old and new.

Read on for a basic introduction, somewhat over-simplified, to orient you in moving back-and-forth between the old and new date-time classes.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), inspired by the highly-successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. The bulk of the functionality was back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, with a further adaptation for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

What java.time type matches [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)? Well, a `java.util.Date` object basically represents a moment on the timeline in UTC, a combination of a date and a time-of-day. We can translate that to any of several types in java.time. Each is discussed below. Note that some new methods have been added to the old date-time classes to facilitate conversions.

[image: diagram of converting from java.util.Date/.Calendar through ZonedDateTime (or OffsetDateTime) to the three Local… types]

### `Instant`

The building block in java.time is an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Generally you should do much of your business logic in UTC. In such work, `Instant` will be used frequently. Pass around `Instant` objects, applying a time zone only for presentation to a user. When you *do* need to apply an offset or time zone, use the types covered further below.

#### From `java.util.Date` to `Instant`

Given that both `Instant` and `java.util.Date` are a moment on the timeline in UTC, we can easily move from a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to an `Instant`. The old class has gained a new method, [`java.util.Date::toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

You can go the other direction, from an `Instant` to a `java.util.Date`. But you may lose information about the fractional second. An `Instant` tracks [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), for up to nine digits after the decimal place such as `2016-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z`. Both java.util.Date & .Calendar are limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), for up to three digits after the decimal place such as `2016-01-23T12:34:56.123Z`. In this example going from `Instant` to `Date` means truncation of the `456789`.

```
java.util.Date myUtilDate = java.util.Date.from(instant);
```

#### From `java.util.Calendar` to `Instant`

What about a [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of a `java.util.Date`?  Internal to the `Calendar` object, the date-time is tracked as a count of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) from the [epoch reference date-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of the first moment of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00.0Z`). So this value can be converted easily to an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myUtilCalendar.toInstant() ;
```

#### From `java.util.GregorianCalendar` to `ZonedDateTime`

Even better, if your [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object is actually a [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) you can easily go directly to a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). This approach has the benefit of retaining the embedded time zone information.

[Downcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) from the [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)) of `Calendar` to the [concrete class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete) of `GregorianCalendar`. Then call the [`toZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--) and [`from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from-java.time.ZonedDateTime-) methods to go back and forth.

```
if (myUtilCalendar instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
    GregorianCalendar gregCal = (GregorianCalendar) myUtilCalendar; // Downcasting from the interface to the concrete class.
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gregCal.toZonedDateTime();  // Create `ZonedDateTime` with same time zone info found in the `GregorianCalendar`
}
```

Going the other direction…

```
java.util.Calendar myUtilCalendar = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from(zdt); // Produces an instant of `GregorianCalendar` which implements `Calendar` interface.
```

As discussed above, beware that you may be **losing information about the fraction of a second**. The [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) in the java.time type (`ZonedDateTime`) gets truncated to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) in the `.Calendar`/`.GregorianCalendar`.

## `OffsetDateTime`

From an `Instant` we can apply an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to move into a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) for some locality. An offset is a number of hours, and possibly minutes and seconds, ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (eastward) or behind UTC (westward). The [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class represents this idea. The result is an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("-04:00"); 
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneOffset);
```

You can go the other direction, from an `OffsetDateTime` to a `java.util.Date`. Extract an `Instant` and then proceed as we saw in code above. As discussed above, any [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) get truncated to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (**data loss**).

```
java.util.Date myUtilDate = java.util.Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Better yet, apply a full [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). A time zone is an offset *plus* rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Applying a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) gets you a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (continent/region). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations commonly seen such as `EST` or `IST` as they are neither standardized nor unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
```

You can go the other direction, from an `ZonedDateTime` to a `java.util.Date`. Extract an `Instant` and then proceed as we saw in code above. As discussed above, any [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) get truncated to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) (**data loss**).

```
java.util.Date myUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

And we saw further above that a `ZonedDateTime` may be converted to a `GregorianCalendar`.

## `LocalDate`

Sometimes you may want a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. For that, use a [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object.

See this Question for more discussion, [Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21242110/642706), especially [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242111/642706) written by the main man behind the invention of both Joda-Time and java.time.

The key is to go through a `ZonedDateTime` (as generated in code above). We need a time zone to determine a date. The date varies around the world, with a new day dawning earlier in the east. For example, after midnight in Paris is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal. So while a `LocalDate` does not *contain* a time zone, a time zone is required to *determine* a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

Converting in the other direction from `LocalDate` to a date-time means inventing a time-of-day. You can choose any time-of-day that makes sense in your business scenario. For most people, the first moment of the day makes sense. You may be tempted to hard code that first moment as the time `00:00:00.0`. In some time zones, that time may not be valid as the first moment because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other anomalies. So let java.time determine the correct time with a call to [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId);
```

## `LocalTime`

On rare occasion you may want only a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone. This concept is represented by the [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. As discussed above with `LocalDate`, we need a time zone to determine a `LocalTime` even though the `LocalTime` object does not contain (does not ‘remember’) that time zone. So, again, we go through a `ZonedDateTime` object obtained from an `Instant` as seen above.

```
LocalTime localTime = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

## `LocalDateTime`

As with the other two `Local…` types, a [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) has no time zone nor offset assigned. As such **you may rarely use** this. It gives you a rough idea of a date-time but is *not* a point on the timeline. Use this if you mean some general date and some time that might be applied to a time zone.

For example, “Christmas starts this year” would be `2016-12-25T00:00:00.0`. Note the lack of any offset or time zone in that textual representation of a `LocalDateTime`. Christmas starts sooner in Delhi India than it does in Paris France, and later still in Montréal Québec Canada. Applying each of those areas’ time zone would yield a different moment on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

[image]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: An instant in time isn't "a combination of a date and a time-of-day" - because that assumes a particular calendar system (and time zone). I agree that `Date` maps to `Instant`, but I think `Calendar` more accurately maps to `ZonedDateTime` (if you're happy to assume a Gregorian calendar) or `ChronoZonedDateTime` if you want to support arbitrary calendar systems.

Comment: Rather than reposting your prior answer you should probably flag this question as a duplicate of the one for which you originally posted this answer.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329

Comment: @JonSkeet I totally agree, but my idea here was to cover the basics, just to get people oriented to the new types. I searched and realized we have various this-to-that conversion questions, but not a general introductory question-answer. I'll add a disclaimer up top.

Comment: @JimGarrison I just wrote this answer (and diagram) from scratch right now. If you can point me to a duplicate, please do.

Comment: This answer looks like an expanded version of http://stackoverflow.com/a/35924696/18157

Comment: @JimGarrison You pointed to a question and answer that was all about generating strings formatted to the ISO 8601 standard. I did not even mention generating strings, formatting, or ISO 8601 at all here (purposely). Nor did I touch on the `java.sql` types here as I did there (purposely). I will grant you, much of this material has been written by me and others in various pieces in various places. But at the moment I was inspired to write a general overview to how to convert back-and-forth between the old types and java.time.

Comment: Maybe I am old school, but where do you base this statement: "The old date-time classes including java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, and java.text.SimpleTextFormat and such have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. "

I have written more than my fair share of java applications and good old java.util.date and java.sql.date where never "poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome", at least to me.

Comment: In addition, IMHO statements  like 'You should use this instead of that' and 'the existing classes are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome' should be backed up with proper proof before made on StackOverflow.

Comment: @chrisl08: No, they really *really* are. They're *awful* APIs. Just look at how much of `java.util.Date` is deprecated. Just look at how many users on Stack Overflow are confused by `Date.toString()` showing the value in the system local time zone, and inferring that `Date` has information about a time zone. Just look at the inheritance relationship between `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`, where `java.sql.Date` is meant to just represent a date, but doesn't even specify what time zone that's supposedly in, when `java.util.Date` is a point in time. I could rant for *hours* about this...

Comment: @chrisl08: You could start with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api

Comment: @chrisl08 Any quick search an Stack Overflow will lead you to a nearly endless flow of confusion and pain caused by those old date-time classes. Their many flaws have been explained many times in many places. Not even debatable at this point in history -- certainly let us **not get into it here**. While those old classes were a brave first attempt (by Taligent and IBM) in an industry that had for too long ignored this difficult but crucial topic of date-time handling, in the end they were nowhere near good enough. Thus Joda-Time, and now its successor, java.time.

Comment: @BasilBourque `Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myUtilCalendar.time() );` ==> `Instant instant = myUtilCalendar.toInstant();`

Comment: Good question and answer. Worth noting the new method on `Calendar`: toInstant(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant-- . `GregorianCalendar` has two new methods: toZonedDateTime() and from(ZonedDateTime)

Comment: @JodaStephen & assylias - Thanks for comments about `.Calendar`. Incorporated into text and diagram.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for trying to make improvements, but the SPACE characters in my code samples are intentional. We have wide-format screens, Retina hi-res displays, so we need not keep coding with the conventions of a [computer terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) screen with 72 columns. Wecanaffordafewspacestomakecodemorereadable.