# Print date in original timezone

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, timestamp-with-timezone

Let's say that my device is in Australia (GMT+10:00).

I have a date "2016-04-22T17:45:00+02:00" received from an API.

I want to display it nicely in the original time zone (GMT+02:00).

So, I used SimpleDateFormat with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ".

```
String date = "2016-04-22T17:45:00+02:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
```

But unfortunately, I can't find a clean way to display the date:

```
sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

uses the device time zone.

So I parsed "manually" the date to extract the time zone to set it in the calendar.

```
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + date.substring(date.length() - 6, date.length())));
```

But it doesn't seems to do the trick.

How can I do this?

Comment: what is your original time zone format ??

Comment: @ldemay: Could you try this (Java8)?DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
  System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-04-22T17:45:00+02:00", dtf)); Also you receive data as +02:00 from your API always?

Comment: @BajiraoShinde The date from API is GMT+02:00. My device is in GMT+10:00. I want to print the date in GMT+02:00.

Comment: @Unknown I unfortunately can't use Java 8 yet. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Unknown No, the API dates can be in any time zone.

Comment: @ldemay The bulk of the functionality of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) has been [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). I *strongly* recommend avoiding the old date-time classes. Some reading on the subject in Stack Overflow should soon convince you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Time Zone = Offset + Rules

> in the original time zone (GMT+02:00).

No, incorrect. The text `GMT+02:00` represents an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), **not a time zone**. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

A time zone is named in the format of `continent/region` such as `America/Montreal` or `Asia/Kolkata`. Always use [these proper names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never the 3-4 abbreviations seen in mainstream media; these are neither standardized nor unique.

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is the new [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time), in practical terms.

## Avoid old date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them. These classes were supplanted by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and its successor the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into [Java 8 and later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). Much of its functionality was back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Learn more at the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

## `OffsetDateTime`

The input string has only an offset-from-UTC, not a full [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So we use the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class to represent this kind of value.

Your input string is fortunately in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So we can directly parse without bothering to define a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2016-04-22T17:45:00+02:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

Call [`OffsetDateTime::toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString--) to generate a string in the same format.

```
String output = odt.toString(); // ISO 8601 formatted string.
```

## `Instant`

Programmers should not be thinking in these kind of local date-times. Generally you should do your business logic, database storage, and data-exchange all in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

In java.time, an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution in [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). We can extract an `Instant` from our `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Always better to use a time zone than just an offset because of the rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time.

You can easily adjust either an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime` into a time zone by applying a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a `ZonedDateTime`. For more discussion, see [my longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155/642706) and [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yzFN.png) on the general topic of converting/adjusting between these classes.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Montreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId_Montreal );
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Montreal = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneId_Montreal );
```

Be aware that when applying a time zone you may see the time-of-day and even the date change. Adjustments may need to be made according to that zone’s rules to accommodate [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other issues.

You can adjust further into other time zones. You mention Australia. That country has many time zones, so you must choose which is appropriate to you (or your user) as they may have different rules either now or in the past or future.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Melbourne = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Melbourne" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Melbourne = zdt_Montreal.withZoneSameInstant( zoneId_Melbourne );
```

You will notice when calling `ZonedDateTime::toString` that the method extends the standard ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

To generate strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for topics of [`java.time.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The `ofLocalized…` methods along with a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) can automatically localize the formatting including translating human language day/month names, and following cultural norms for order of elements, period-versus-comma, and so on.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As I can see Date object has no information about timezone. So a way but not the best can be parsing timezone from date string and set it to SimpleDateFormat. Something like:

```
String date = "2016-04-22T17:45:00+02:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// tz is +02:00
String tz;
if (date.contains("+"))
    tz = date.substring(date.indexOf("+"));
else
    tz = date.substring(date.lastIndexOf("-"));

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + tz));
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Your way of parsing the tz is sexier than mine, but I hoped the framework could answer this problem without any "tricks". Thanks
EDIT tz can be "+" or "-"

Comment: @Idemay I updated my answer based on your comment. I dont know and could not find and easier way. Ofcourse that doesnt mean there is not any.