# Parse CIM_DateTime with milliseconds to Java Date

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, wmi

I am trying to convert a DateTime value retrieved from Windows Management Interface into a Java (1.7) Date; ultimately to milliseconds since the epoch. The [format is specified here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx).

An example that I am trying to parse is `20160513072950.782000-420` which is 2016-05-13 at 07:29:50 plus 782 milliseconds, in my local timezone (-420 minutes = UTC-7 hours).  The digits after the decimal are fractional seconds; in theory up to 6 digits of microseconds, but in practice only the first 4 digits are nonzero.

I initially attempted to parse using a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) specifying the three digits of milliseconds that I wanted to parse:

```
SimpleDateFormat cimDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
Date date = cimDateFormat.parse(s, new ParsePosition(0));
```

My reasoning was that specifying the three digits of milliseconds with `SSS` would stop the parsing.  Unfortunately, this didn't work; many more than 782 milliseconds in the above example were added.

I eventually got it to work as desired by trimming the string to the required characters:

```
SimpleDateFormat cimDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.S");
Date date = cimDateFormat.parse(s.substring(0, 18), new ParsePosition(0));
```

In this case, I only included one `S` for milliseconds but it parsed all three.

I can't find anything in the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc that clearly explains what's going on at the end of this parsing.  Specific questions:

1. Why does it keep parsing past the specified number of digits in the `SSS` case?
2. Why does a single `S` parse all 3 millisecond digits?
3. Other than truncating the string like I did, is there any other way of telling the `SimpleDateFormat` to stop parsing the string at the indicated position?

Comment: _For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields_

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks -- that answers 1 and 2. Now for 3, is there an 'adjacent field' I could add after the SSS that says "extra characters, ignore"?

Comment: Not ignore, no. The 6 characters confuse me. Are they fractional seconds? Doesn't seem like it, but why would there be 6 digits for that? Why not collapse into the other fields? `SimpleDateFormat` considers the field as milliseconds, so a value like `782000` would add that many milliseconds to the total date. You'll have to process your string to make it compatible with the patterns of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Based on many sample data points, the 6 characters represent microseconds; however, Windows only records time in 100-microsecond increments so only the first 4 of those 6 characters ever had data in them.  I'm ignoring the 4th character and only want to parse the first 3 digits as milliseconds.  Thanks for the more detailed response regarding pre-processing the string (e.g. to change the -420 minutes to the correct -0700 timezone); if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Modify the input

As far as I know, none of the three common date-time frameworks for Java (the old bundled java.util.Date/.Calendar/java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes, the Joda-Time framework, or the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later) allow for an offset-from-UTC as a total number of minutes.

As suggested by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis), you must modify the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to convert from a number of total minutes to the standard number of hours and minutes (and seconds – a possibility ignored by that odd Microsoft format). So `-420` should become `-07:00` or `-07:00:00`.

## java.time

You are using the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. The old classes are now legacy, and have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, and largely [back-ported to Java  6 & 7 by the ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The java.time classes have a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), for up to nine digits of a decimal fraction of second. So no problem handling your inputs 4-6 digits of fractional second.

Our strategy has two parts: (a) Modify the input to convert that offset-from-UTC, and (b) Parse the modified input string as a date-time object.

### Modify input

First we change the input from `20160513072950.782000-420` to `20160513072950.782000-07:00:00`. We do this by extracting the characters trailing after the `+` or `-`, the `420` in this case.

```
// Modify the input to replace offset as a number of minutes to the standard format, a number of hours, minutes, and seconds.
String input = "20160513072950.782000-420";
String offsetInMinutesAsString = input.substring ( 22 );
```

Convert that to a `long`, and create a `LocalTime` object so that we can generate a string in the format of `HH:mm:ss`.

```
long offsetInMinutes = Long.parseLong ( offsetInMinutesAsString );
LocalTime offsetAsLocalTime = LocalTime.MIN.plusMinutes ( offsetInMinutes );
String offsetAsString = offsetAsLocalTime.format ( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME );
```

Replace those trailing characters with our generated string.

```
String inputModified = ( input.substring ( 0 , 22 ) + offsetAsString );
```

## Parse string to date-time object

Define a [custom formatting pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) by which to parse that string into a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
// Parse the modified input as an OffsetDateTime.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSSSSZZZZZ" , Locale.US );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( inputModified , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | inputModified: " + inputModified + " | odt: " + odt );
```

> input: 20160513072950.782000-420 | inputModified: 20160513072950.782000-07:00:00 | odt: 2016-05-13T07:29:50.782-07:00

### Convert

I strongly suggest avoiding the old date-time classes. But if you must use a `java.util.Date` object to interoperate with old date-time code, you can convert.

Look for new methods added to the old classes for conversion. For this conversion we use [`java.util.Date.from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-). We need to feed that conversion method a [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). We can extract one from our `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

For more info about converting, including a nifty diagram, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155/642706) to another Question. Keep in mind that we are working with only a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) in our input strings and our `OffsetDateTime`, not a full time zone. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is an offset *plus* rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Both the `Instant` and the `java.util.Date` are in UTC (an offset of zero).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!    I'm developing for a project requiring Java 1.7 so I can't use the new time, and since I am primarily interested in getting to a "milliseconds since the epoch" (Corresponding to `System.currentTimeMillis()` -- The value I am parsing is a process start time; by subtracting from current time I get uptime) the Date is an intermediate step and adding a Joda Time dependency just for this seems like overkill.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Notice the link to the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project where much of the functionality has been brought to Java 6 & 7. Simply drop the jar into your project.

Answer (score 0):

While I accepted Basil Bourque's answer and have, for the past two years, kept the `threetenbp` dependency in my project, I managed to throw together a quick parsing using `Calendar` that does the same thing and works for my needs.   Add exception checking, etc., but this gives an identical result using JDK1.1 code, and may be useful for others.  Note, however, that this approach is *not thread safe*, and the accepted answer should be preferred.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(0, 4)));
    // Calendar uses 0-indexed months
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(4, 6)) - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(6, 8)));
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(8, 10)));
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(10, 12)));
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(12, 14)));
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(15, 18)));
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    // Offset from UTC is in minutes
    return c.getTimeInMillis() + Integer.parseInt(cimDate.substring(22)) * 60_000L;*
```