# How can I convert a String formatted in this way into a Date using Java?

Tags: java, date

Into a Java application I have this String representing a timestamp containing values like this: **2009-10-17 05:45:14.000**

As you can see the string represents the year, the month, the day, the hour, the minute, the second and the millisencond.

I have to convert a String like this into a Date object (if possible bringing also the millisecond information, is it possible?)

How can I correctly implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse CIM\_DateTime with milliseconds to Java Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308672/parse-cim-datetime-with-milliseconds-to-java-date) - There are probably dozens of similar questions. Check this one. It's not exactly the same, but it does take into consideration date+time (including millis). In that ansewer, find the bit that uses `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a given string date according to a given pattern, it also supports milliseconds, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date=format.parse("2009-10-17 05:45:14.050");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, you should use the classes in the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/index.html)
Class `LocalDateTime` stores a date and a time up to nanosecond precision.
Here is a snippet showing how to parse a string into an instance of `LocalDateTime`

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2009-10-17 05:45:14.000";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
    }
}
```