# DateTimeFormatter to DateFormat conversion

Tags: java, date

How to convert a DateTimeFormatter to DateFormat ? I want to cast **DateTimeFormatter to DateFormat** ? Is it possible ?

I have a object of DateTimeFormatter and I want to pass it to a method whose parameter only accepts DateFormat.

Comment: For what method your need DateFormat? 
Maybe your should find out appropriate method whose parameter is DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: you can convert a DateTimeFormatter to a java.text.Format with : java.text.Format oldformat = dateTimeFormatter.toFormat();

Comment: @ben Can you provide a link to class doc? I see no such method on either DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: See here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html : "Some applications may need to use the older java.text.Format class for formatting. The toFormat() method returns an implementation of java.text.Format."

Answer (score 3):

There is no backward conversion from `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to the old formatter class.

The newer java.time classes are intended to supplant the old ones. They are not intended to be mixed or interoperate. The old date-time classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

## Go forward, not backward

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy. Classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.DateFormat/.SimpleDateFormat should be avoided.

Those old classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of that functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project, and further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.

Instead, go *forward*. Convert your old date-time objects to the modern java.time classes. New methods have been added to the old classes to facilitate conversion of your data.

If you have a java.util.Date, call `toInstant()`. If you have a java.util.Calendar object, convert to a `ZonedDateTime`.

To get started, see [my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154) and [my Answer with nifty diagram of types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155).

Comment: Yes, but what to do when you are using an API (jackson-databind) using `DateFormat` such as in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955104/using-datetimeformatter-with-objectmapper