# Using DateTimeFormatter with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, objectmapper

Prior to Java8, we used to set DateFormat with ObjectMapper as follows

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
ObjectMapper mapper = <SomeInstantiation>
mapper.setDateFormat(df);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Now that we have `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` which is *thread-safe* and more robust unlike `SimpleDateFormat`. I want to replace above settings on `ObjectMapper`.

How do I set `DateTimeFormatter` with `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: From what I gathered, you can use "Configuration Overrides" to do something similar. See [the 2.8 patchnote](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.8#configuration-overrides) and [this github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/issues/12).

Answer (score 11):

You can try the following:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

LocalDateTimeDeserializer dateTimeDeserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(formatter);
LocalDateTimeSerializer dateTimeSerializer = new LocalDateTimeSerializer(formatter);

JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule(); 
javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, dateTimeDeserializer);
javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, dateTimeSerializer);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
```

The [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```