# Shift date an hour when in dst

Tags: java, jodatime, java.util.calendar

I am processing a file line by line.

Each line has a date in the following format: YYMMDD HHMM

The file is basically recording a reading every 15 minutes. The recording is using day light savings for the time zone it is in. The issue I am having is during spring ahead and fall back. The recording is duplicating dates when fall back occurs and a gap when fall back occurs.

**Fallback example:**

141102 0100

141102 0115

141102 0130

141102 0145

141102 0200

141102 0115 - duplicate

141102 0130 - duplicate

141102 0145 - duplicate

141102 0200 - duplicate

**Spring forward example:**

150308 0200

150308 0315

What I need to be able to do, is shift all the dates forward an hour when in daylight savings time.

The program I am working on is using java.util.Calendar currently. I have tried doing the shift using the java Calendar and am running into lots of issues with adding the dates. I assume the problem to be that it is trying to correct DST issues itself, when all I want to do is shift the date by an hour. It also has an issue with detecting that gap. For example it thinks that the first 1:15 - 2:00 is in daylight time, when this is not the case for it.

Basically what I want is to change the fallback example to everything that falls in this date range to shift back an hour:

**Fallback example:**

141102 0100 no change

141102 0115 no change

141102 0130 no change

141102 0145 no change

141102 0200 no change

141102 0115 to 141102 0215

141102 0130 to 141102 0230

141102 0145 to 141102 0245

141102 0200 to 141102 0300

Keeps on changing date until it hits the spring forward

150308 0200 to 150308 0300

150308 0315 no change.

I have tried lots of ways, and can't seem to come to a solution. I am not opposed to using Joda Time as I've been looking into that a bit as well. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So what you really want to do is to convert the date to a filename using a time zone that doesn't change its offset in the summer, right?

Comment: It's not a filename, but a line in the file that has this 'timestamp'. I want to shift that timestamp an hour when is dst so that I don't have a gap or duplicate entries.

Comment: OK, but wouldn't just using a timezone without daylight savings in your date format achieve that?  Or am I missing something?  Standard practice is to use UTC for timestamps in log files, but presumably you'd prefer whichever timezone lines up with yours in winter.

Answer (score 4):

## UTC

Always use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for data exchange and this kind of readings log. Always, always, always use UTC. Think of UTC as the *One True Time* and other time zones as deviations from UTC.

By the way, [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is *not* the only problem to worry about with zoned date-time values. Other anomalies occur in various time zones resulting in [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) shifting forward or backward. The solution is easy: Avoid all time zones – **Use UTC**.

## `Instant`

The `Instant` class captures a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. This should be you go-to class for date-time work.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

## Strings

For logging, generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Stick with the proven ISO 8601 formats rather than invent your own.

The java.time classes including `Instant` use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify formatting patterns.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-11-02T21:10:05.321Z

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-11-02T21:10:05.321Z" );
```

And always include the century `20` in your dates. Omitting just creates so much opportunity for errors in misinterpreting. Storage and memory really is cheap enough that we can afford the two extra digits.

## Time zone indicator

Always include a time zone or offset-from-UTC indicator with your serialized date-time values.

In the `Instant::toString` result seen above, the `Z` stands for `Zulu` which means UTC.

## Parsing strings

Here is code to parse your date-time strings. We parse as [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) first, without any time zone or offset, because your input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset. Then we assign a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), to see how it handles the moment of DST cut-over.

I assume your time zone in question uses a DST fall-back cutover of 2 AM. I used `America/Montreal` as an example of such.

```
List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>( 2 );
inputs.add( "141102 0115" );  // 1 AM
inputs.add( "141102 0215" );  // 2 AM

for( String input : inputs ) {
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuMMdd HHmm" );
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );

    // At 2 AM in this zone, the clock falls back one hour for DST cutover. The 1 AM hour repeats.
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );

    System.out.println( "input: " + input );
    System.out.println( "ldt: " + ldt );
    System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
    System.out.println( "instant: " + zdt.toInstant() );
    System.out.println("");
}
```

> input: 141102 0115
>
> ldt: 2014-11-02T01:15
>
> zdt: 2014-11-02T01:15-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> instant: 2014-11-02T05:15:00Z

…and…

> input: 141102 0215
>
> ldt: 2014-11-02T02:15
>
> zdt: 2014-11-02T02:15-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> instant: 2014-11-02T07:15:00Z

You can [see this code live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/zJ1k12). Note the two hour difference in UTC values (`Z`).

The behavior we see is documented.

> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. In the case of an overlap, where clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. This method uses the earlier offset typically corresponding to "summer".

Where the 1:15 AM is ambiguous, could be either the first or second occurrence, java.time goes with the first.

You could play a guessing-game to try to adjust these poorly-designed strings. If you are sure you have at least one sample during every clock hour, you could keep track of previous samples and see if the sample being processed has a clock-time earlier than the previous. If so you could assume this is a DST fall-back cutover, and add an hour with `plusHours( 1 )`.

```
if( processingZdt.toLocalDateTime().isBefore( previousZdt.toLocalDateTime() ) { 
    processingZdt.plusHours( 1 ) ;  // A hack; I am *not* recommending this.
    …
```

But this is a risky hack of a solution. I'm not sure this work, as I've not thought it through. If desperate, perhaps you can make it work.

The much wise approach is prevention: **Use UTC**.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great response to my answer, and was a great insight into how to do this in the future, very helpful. The problem is that I am doing work on a program that was created over 15 years ago and now they want to add to it and I am sort of bound to the java.util.Calendar class as they use it throughout their program.

Comment: @DHines You can [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime--) a `GregorianCalendar` to a `ZonedDateTime` and extract an `Instant` for UTC. `ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime();` See [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706) for more info on converting. The legacy date-time classes really are a troublesome mess and should be avoided. That's why Sun and Oracle agreed to inventing java.time.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that question. It was insightful and I think will help. I'm not sure it 100% solves my problem. The way that the file comes in, there will be duplicate dates when they have the fall back (i.e. two inputs of 141102 0115), and a gap when they have spring forward(i.e. inputs 150308 0200 and 150308 0315). I can't change the way the file comes in, I have to handle it. So I guess what I am trying to accomplish is when I am in the dst time I need to shift all the data an hour.

Comment: @DHines That shifting is what I'm showing in the last part of my Answer. I showed how to parse your strings, how to apply your time zone, and the very last bit of code shows how to compare items of your data and shift forward an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Daylight savings
Many countries in the world adopt what is called Daylight Saving Time (DST), the practice of advance the clock by an hour in the summer (well, not exactly in the summer in all countries but let's bear with this) when the daylight savings time starts.

When the daylight time ends, clocks are set back by an hour. This is done to make better use of natural daylight.

ZonedDateTime is fully aware of DST.

For an example, let's take a country where DST is fully observed, like Italy (UTC/GMT +2).

In 2015, DST started in Italy on March, 29th and ended on October, 25th. This means that on:

```
March, 29 2015 at 2:00:00 A.M. clocks were turned forward 1 hour to
March, 29 2015 at 3:00:00 A.M. local daylight time instead
(So a time like March, 29 2015 2:30:00 A.M. didn't actually exist!)

October, 25 2015 at 3:00:00 A.M. clocks were turned backward 1 hour to
October, 25 2015 at 2:00:00 A.M. local daylight time instead
(So a time like October, 25 2015 2:30:00 A.M. actually existed twice!)
```

If we create an instance of LocalDateTime with this date/time and print it:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 3, 29, 2, 30);
System.out.println(ldt);
```

The result will be:

```
2015-03-29T02:30
```

But if we create an instance of ZonedDateTime for Italy (notice that the format uses a city, not a country) and printed:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
     2015, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
System.out.println(zdt);
```

The result will be just like in the real world when using DST:

```
2015-03-29T03:30+02:00[Europe/Rome]
```

But be careful. We have to use a regional ZoneId, a ZoneOffset won't do the trick because this class doesn't have the zone rules information to account for DST:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of(
     2015, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(
     2015, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC+2"));
System.out.println(zdt1); System.out.println(zdt2);
```

The result will be:

```
2015-03-29T02:30+02:00[UTC+02:00] 2015-03-29T02:30+02:00
```

When we create an instance of ZonedDateTime for Italy, we have to add an hour to see the effect (otherwise we we'll be creating the ZonedDateTime at 3:00 of the new time):

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
    2015, 10, 25, 2, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt.plusHours(1);
System.out.println(zdt);
System.out.println(zdt2);
```

The result will be:

```
2015-10-25T02:30+02:00[Europe/Rome] 2015-10-25T02:30+01:00[Europe/Rome]
```

We also need to be careful when adjusting the time across the DST boundary with a version of the methods plus() and minus() that takes a TemporalAmount implementation, in other words, a Period or a Duration. This is because both differ in their treatment of daylight savings time.

Consider one hour before the beginning of DST in Italy:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(
    2015, 3, 29, 1, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
```

When we add a Duration of one day:

```
System.out.println(zdt.plus(Duration.ofDays(1)));
```

The result is:

```
2015-03-30T02:00+02:00[Europe/Rome]
```

When we add a Period of one day:

```
System.out.println(zdt.plus(Period.ofDays(1)));
```

The result is:

```
2015-03-30T01:00+02:00[Europe/Rome]
```

The reason is that Period adds a conceptual date, while Duration adds exactly one day (24 hours or 86, 400 seconds) and when it crosses the DST boundary, one hour is added, and the final time is 02:00 instead of 01:00.

=======================================================================
Java 8 introduce java.time.LocalDateTime:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTimeBeforeDST = LocalDateTime
  .of(2018, 3, 25, 1, 55);

assertThat(localDateTimeBeforeDST.toString())
  .isEqualTo("2018-03-25T01:55");
```

We can observe how a LocalDateTime is conforming to the ISO-8601 rules.

It's completely unaware of Zones and Offsets, though, that's why we need to convert it into a fully DST-aware java.time.ZonedDateTime:

```
ZoneId italianZoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeBeforeDST = localDateTimeBeforeDST
  .atZone(italianZoneId);

assertThat(zonedDateTimeBeforeDST.toString())
  .isEqualTo("2018-03-25T01:55+01:00[Europe/Rome]");
```

As we can see, now the date incorporates two fundamental trailing pieces of information: +01:00 is the ZoneOffset, while [Europe/Rome] is the ZoneId.

let's trigger DST through the addition of ten minutes:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeAfterDST = zonedDateTimeBeforeDST
  .plus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

assertThat(zonedDateTimeAfterDST.toString())
  .isEqualTo("2018-03-25T03:05+02:00[Europe/Rome]");
```

Again, we see how both the time and the zone offset are shifting forward, and still keeping the same distance:

```
Long deltaBetweenDatesInMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES
  .between(zonedDateTimeBeforeDST,zonedDateTimeAfterDST);
assertThat(deltaBetweenDatesInMinutes)
  .isEqualTo(10);
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are not considered complete. It's generally a good practice to add an explanation or summary

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, it was edited greatly so it's perfect now :)