# Adding a month to a date in Java two ways gives two different results (leap year philosophy?)

Tags: java, date, localdate, java.util.calendar

Assuming Jan 31, 2000, a leap year, the following two ways of adding a month give me different results. Am I doing something wrong or are these two different philosophies of handling leap-year months? And, if these two approaches are just a philosophy difference, how would you know which method to pick?

**Method 1:** using `LocalDate plusMonths()`:

```
LocalDate atestDate = LocalDate.parse("2000-01-31");
System.out.println("One month in future using LocalDate.addMonths() " +   atestDate.plusMonths(1));
```

Output:

```
One month in future using LocalDate.addMonths() 2000-02-29
```

---

**Method 2:** using `Calendar`:

```
Calendar zcal = Calendar.getInstance();
zcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
zcal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
zcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
System.out.println("ONE MONTH IN FUTURE using Calendar: " 
 + zcal.getTime());
```

Output:

```
ONE MONTH IN FUTURE using Calendar: Thu Mar 02 2000
```

Why are these two dates' output not the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify Java Version also.

Comment: `zcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0)` does not change the calendar’s date.  You’re adding zero to it.  Also, `zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1)` sets the month to February, because [Calendar.FEBRUARY is equal to 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.FEBRUARY), not 2.  Calendar.JANUARY is 0.  Many have argued that this was a design error, but regardless, if you use the constants instead of literal int values, you won’t have the problem.

Comment: Actually, for me, anyway, zcal.add(Calendar.Month, 0) does change the month by one. Try it.

Comment: Correction to my comment above, I should have done: zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY). Then zcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1) would be correct as expected. My mistake.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
zcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
zcal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
```

This defines the date of February 31st, 2000, which, due to lenient measuring, is equated to March 2nd, 2000. Month values are zero-indexed.

Setting strict:

```
zcal.setLenient(false);
```

We get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH: 1 -> 2
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2829)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1755)
at Employee.Tester.main(Tester.java:19)
```

So you can see that the interpolation was shifted over to March. If you wish to hard-code dates for testing purposes, I would recommend using strict validation to avoid these cases. There have been other documented issues related to setting values that make things messy.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

**Just use `LocalDate`** and forget all about `Calendar` (troublesome legacy class).

```
LocalDate.parse( "2000-01-31" ).plusMonths( 1 ).toString()
```

> 2000-02-29

## Method 1

> Method 1: using LocalDate plusMonths():

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class documentation explains that it first adds the month-number, and leaves the day-of-month alone. If that day-of-month is not valid in that month (29, 30, or 31), then it adjusts backwards to the last valid day-of-month.

> This method adds the specified amount to the months field in three steps:
>
> 1. Add the input months to the month-of-year field
> 2. Check if the resulting date would be invalid
> 3. Adjust the day-of-month to the last valid day if necessary
>
> For example, 2007-03-31 plus one month would result in the invalid date 2007-04-31. Instead of returning an invalid result, the last valid day of the month, 2007-04-30, is selected instead.

Seems like a smart approach to me.

In your example, `LocalDate` first changed `2000-01-31` to `2000-02-31`. There is no 31st in February, so it walked back to 30. But no Feb 30th either. So it walked further back to 29. Bingo! In that year in that month, there is indeed a 29th day because the year 2000 is a [Leap Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). So the answer is `2000-02-29`.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2000-01-31" )
         .plusMonths( 1 )
         .toString()
```

> 2000-02-29

## Method 2

> Method 2: using Calendar:

**Don’t bother.**

This terribly troublesome old `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes as defined in [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Specifically, replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

**Never touch `Calendar` class again.** Save yourself some pain and headache, and pretend this class never existed.

Furthermore, `Calendar` was a date-with-time value. Not appropriate for a date-only value like yours in the Question.

### Convert legacy <–> modern

If you must inter-operate with code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert between the legacy classes and *java.time* by calling new conversion methods added to the old classes. For more info, see the Question, [*Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706)

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had in the posting above turned out to be a typo.

```
Calendar zcal = Calendar.getInstance();
zcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
zcal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
zcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
System.out.println("ONE MONTH IN FUTURE using Calendar: " 
 + zcal.getTime());
```

Should have been:

```
Calendar zcal = Calendar.getInstance();
zcal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
zcal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
zcal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
zcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("ONE MONTH IN FUTURE using Calendar: " 
 + zcal.getTime());
```

Then I get the expected matching date.

Thanks to all who answered! :)